# How to add my model to goAdmin dashboard?

Tags: go

I have tried to add my custom Post model to the goAdmin dashboard but it does not appear on the bar - as it should. I have created setup according to the [documentation](https://go-admin.com/) along with running initialization [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoAdminGroup/go-admin/master/data/admin.pgsql) for Postgres database.

Model in `post-model.go`.

```
type Post struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title       string
    Description string
}
```

In `admin.go` I bind table from other file and initialize the router.

```
func ConfigureAdmin(router *gin.Engine) {
    eng := engine.Default()
    adminPlugin := admin.NewAdmin(datamodel.Generators)
    adminPlugin.AddGenerator("Post", tables.GetPostTable)
    eng.AddPlugins(adminPlugin)
    cfg := loadConfig()
    _ = eng.AddConfig(&cfg).Use(router)
}


func loadConfig() config.Config {
    cfg := config.Config{
        Databases: config.DatabaseList{
            "default": {
                Host:         os.Getenv("POSTGRES_HOST"),
                Port:         os.Getenv("POSTGRES_PORT"),
                User:         os.Getenv("POSTGRES_USER"),
                Pwd:          os.Getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
                Name:         os.Getenv("POSTGRES_DB"),
                MaxIdleConns: 50,
                MaxOpenConns: 150,
                Driver:       os.Getenv("DB_DRIVER"),
            },
        },
        UrlPrefix: "admin",
        Store: config.Store{
            Path:   "./uploads",
            Prefix: "uploads",
        },
        Language: language.EN,
    }
    return cfg
}
```

In `post-table.go` I initialize Post table:

```
func GetPostTable(ctx *context.Context) table.Table {
    dsn, err := loadEnv()
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    postTable := table.NewDefaultTable(table.DefaultConfigWithDriverAndConnection("postgresql", dsn))
    formList := postTable.GetForm()
    formList.AddField("ID", "id", db.Integer, form.Default)
    formList.AddField("Title", "title", db.Varchar, form.Text)
    formList.AddField("Description", "description", db.Varchar, form.Text)
    return postTable
}
```

Posts table is present in the database as shown below.

```
gorm_db=# \dt
                 List of relations
 Schema |           Name           | Type  | Owner 
--------+--------------------------+-------+-------
 public | goadmin_menu             | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_operation_log    | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_permissions      | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_role_menu        | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_role_permissions | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_role_users       | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_roles            | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_session          | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_site             | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_user_permissions | table | gorm
 public | goadmin_users            | table | gorm
 public | posts                    | table | gorm
```

Operator and administrator accounts (users table) which were created by initialization script are visible in admin panel.

Bar structure looks like this:

```
Dashboard
Admin >
        Users
        Roles
        Permission
        Menu
        Operation log
```

Answer (score 0):

bar items are configured using admin -> menu, you just add link

Comment: How can I add this link and where?

Comment: use menu, Admin -> Menu items, login with admin permissions